# trouble fixing memory leak iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have 3 memory leaks in my application and i don't find how to fix it. I'm kind of new to xcode and objective c. Here is the code i have:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2( [[DatabaseController sharedDatabaseController] getDb], sqlQueryConverted, -1, &dbStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){

        //Run the query
        while ( sqlite3_step(dbStatement) == SQLITE_ROW ) 
        {    


            const char *name = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 0);
            int courseId = sqlite3_column_int(dbStatement, 1);
            const char *location = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 2);
            const char *date = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 3);

            //Convert the returnedElement char to string
            nameConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name];
            locationConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:location];
            dateConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];

            Course *course = [[[Course alloc]initWithName:nameConverted _id:courseId location:locationConverted courseDate:dateConverted] autorelease];

            //Add the course to the to a temporary list to remove duplicated items            
            [tempResults addObject:course];

        }  
        [nameConverted release];
        [locationConverted release];
        [dateConverted release];
    }
```

I have tried to autorelease it too. This code is being used to filter a search and reload a search display table. If i put the `release` line in the `while` statement the application would crash if i type 2 letters. How could i fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I've been going back and forth with this problem with no luck. I've come to the conclusion that there's something wrong with Instruments because it's still showing memory leaks. Here's the code as it is today and as i believe should fix the problem:

```
NSString *nameConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name];
            NSString *locationConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:location];
            NSString *dateConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];

            Course *course = [[[Course alloc]initWithName:nameConverted _id:courseId location:locationConverted courseDate:dateConverted] autorelease];

            //Add the course to the to a temporary list to remove duplicated items            
            [tempResults addObject:course];
            course = nil;
            [course release];
            [nameConverted release];
            nameConverted = nil;
            [locationConverted release];
            locationConverted = nil;
            [dateConverted release];
            dateConverted = nil;
            NSLog(@"course retain count %i",[course retainCount]);
            NSLog(@"name coverted retain count %i",[nameConverted retainCount]);
            NSLog(@"location coverted retain count %i",[locationConverted retainCount]);
            NSLog(@"date coverted retain count %i",[dateConverted retainCount]);
```

The logs are telling me that the `retainCount = 0;` so i don't understand why there's a memory leak. Can you guys give me some advice?

Thanks again.

Comment: course = nil;
            [course release];
Is a leak. By setting it to nil you lose the object without ever releasing it. Just use [course release] to release.

Answer (score 2):

You're leaking at each loop. You are only releasing the 3 lasts NSString. Everytime you re-assign a new NSString to your 3 variables (nameConverted, locationConverted, dateConverted) you loose the reference to the NSString objects they are pointing too. That means memory leaking. You only release the 3 last ones of them, when you get out of your While loop.

Comment: @Deepak : Let him find the solution, plizz ;-)

Comment: I've tried to do as you say but i didn't succeed, can you please see the Edits ? Thanks.

Comment: Plizzzzz, invert the two lines :  course = nil; [course release]; !! Asking a nil pointer to release something is pointless :-) Ask him to release what is pointing at, THEN set it to nil for security sake.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a memory block each while loop, and then only releasing it once. So if your while loop runs over 10 times, each string has a retain count of 10 but only released once.

To fix, put your 3 releases inside your while loop like this:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2( [[DatabaseController sharedDatabaseController] getDb], sqlQueryConverted, -1, &dbStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){

        //Run the query
        while ( sqlite3_step(dbStatement) == SQLITE_ROW ) 
        {    


            const char *name = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 0);
            int courseId = sqlite3_column_int(dbStatement, 1);
            const char *location = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 2);
            const char *date = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(dbStatement, 3);

            //Convert the returnedElement char to string
            nameConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name];
            locationConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:location];
            dateConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];

            Course *course = [[[Course alloc]initWithName:nameConverted _id:courseId location:locationConverted courseDate:dateConverted] autorelease];

            //Add the course to the to a temporary list to remove duplicated items            
            [tempResults addObject:course];

        [nameConverted release];
        [locationConverted release];
        [dateConverted release];

        }  

    }
```

Comment: as i said before, the application crashes if i put the 3 releases in the while loop. That's why i'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use:

```
nameConverted = [[NSString initWithUTF8String:name] autorelease];
locationConverted = [[NSString initWithUTF8String:location] autorelease];
dateConverted = [[NSString initWithUTF8String:date] autorelease];
```

And removing the releases outside the loop?
Also do not autoremove the course object, release it after adding it to tempResults.

Comment: Try them with NSString* nameConverted = .... these vars are temp for the loop only right? Just autorelease them in the same line

Comment: Using autorelease in a loop like that is bad practice as the memory will build up until the pool flushes. Better to manually release during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be doing it.

```
NSString *nameConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:name];
NSString *locationConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:location];
NSString *dateConverted = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];

Course *course = [[Course alloc] initWithName:nameConverted _id:courseId location:locationConverted courseDate:dateConverted];
[tempResults addObject:course];
[course release];

[dateConverted release];
[locationConverted release];
[nameConverted release];
```